# Can strawberries be grown year-round indoors?

Tags: indoors, light, strawberries

Are there particular varieties that are best suited for indoor growing?

Will the plant die after producing fruit after x amount of harvests?

Are particular lighting schedules required to produce fruit?

Temperatures will be regulated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this [link](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/strawberry/strawberry-plants-indoors.htm) might be insightful.

Basically, it says they need six hours of sun per day (or artificial plant lighting). I imagine that should be good for fruit as long as it gets enough red light, potassium and phosphorus. The article doesn't mention anything about how fruit specifically relates to light, but it implies you can get fruit with six hours of sunlight a day. Other than lighting, strawberries should be easy to grow indoors from the sound of it.

The site recommends Alpine strawberries, because they have a clumping habit instead of a ranging one, but if you don't mind ranging, I don't suppose it matters a lot which variety you get. I could be wrong.

One great thing about growing strawberries indoors is that you can avoid a lot of the pests and diseases that plague strawberries. This may increase their lifespan and increase yields, but I've never tried it. I haven't found information on how many harvests you can get before the plant dies, but there's another question on here that relates to that in an outdoor context.